# SQL Query to find winners within a contest

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which returns to me results as follows:

```
  Race   | Candidate | Total Votes | MaxNoOfWinners
    ---------------------------------------------------
    1      | 1         | 5000        | 3
    1      | 2         | 6700        | 3
    2      | 1         | 100         | 3
    2      | 2         | 200         | 3
    2      | 3         | 300         | 3
    2      | 4         | 400         | 3
    ...
```

I was wondering if there was a query that could be written to return only the winners (based on the MaxNoOfWinners and TotalVotes) for a certain race. So for the above i would only get back

```
Race   | Candidate | Total Votes | MaxNoOfWinners
---------------------------------------------------
1      | 1         | 5000        | 3
1      | 2         | 6700        | 3
2      | 2         | 200         | 3
2      | 3         | 300         | 3
2      | 4         | 400         | 3
...
```

Comment: Why would the winners for race #2 include those that got votes of 100, 200, and 300, but not the larger one of 400?

Comment: Also, your database design is very flawed because it's not properly normalized. What happens when you have two rows with the same Race but a different value in MaxNoOfWinners?

Comment: thanks for catching that. i've fixed that error

Comment: You fixed that but, IMHO, the one with 100 votes should be out, not the one with 300 votes...

Comment: @tom i'm mentioned that the results above were returned from a query. The data is normalized so there is a master table with a raceid and a MaxNoOfwinners .

Comment: @zSysop If you are not sure of what you want as a result, how will anyone else understand and help solve your problem? :) Is there any logic/requirement for the result you are looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution... I did not test so there may be typos.  The idea is is use the RANK() function of SQL Server to give a ranking by Race based on votes and not include those that don't meet the criteria.  Note, using RANK() and not ROW_NUMBER() will include ties in the result.

```
WITH RankedResult AS
(
  SELECT Race, Candidate, [Total Votes], MaxNoOfWinners, RANK ( )  OVER (PARTITION BY Race ORDER BY [Total Votes] DESC) AS aRank
  FROM Results
)
SELECT Race, Candidate, [Total Votes], MaxNoOfWinners
FROM RankedResult
WHERE aRANK <= MaxNumberOfWinners
```

Comment: You can't use windowed functions directly in a `where` clause though.

Comment: You can't put a windowing function in the WHERE clause

Comment: @Martin, @Erik - OK, I put it in a CTE.  Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete working sample that assumes two tables race and candiate

```
Create Table #Race(Race_id int , MaxNoOfwinners int ) 

INSERT INTO #Race (Race_id , MaxNoOfwinners)
VALUES (1,3), 
       (2,3),
       (3,1)


CREATE TABLE #Candidate (CandidateID int , Race_ID int , Total_Votes int )
INSERT INTO #Candidate (CandidateID  , Race_ID  , Total_Votes  )
VALUES (1,1,5000),
        (2,1,6700),
        (1,2,100),
        (2,2,200),
        (3,2,300),       
        (4,2,400),        
        (1,3,42),
        (2,3,22)


;WITH CTE as (
SELECT 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY race_id ORDER BY  race_id, total_votes DESC ) num,
    CandidateID  , Race_ID  , Total_Votes
From 
    #Candidate)
SELECT * FROM cte inner join #Race r
on CTE.Race_ID = r.Race_id
and num <= r.MaxNoOfwinners

DROP TABLE #Race
DROP TABLE #Candidate
```

With the following results

```
num                  CandidateID Race_ID     Total_Votes Race_id     MaxNoOfwinners
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------
1                    2           1           6700        1           3
2                    1           1           5000        1           3
1                    4           2           400         2           3
2                    3           2           300         2           3
3                    2           2           200         2           3
1                    1           3           42          3           1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH q0 AS (SELECT qry.*, rank() AS r 
   FROM qry OVER (PARTITION BY race ORDER BY total_votes DESC))
SELECT q0.race, q0.candidate, q0.total_votes FROM q0 WHERE r<=q0.max_winners;
```

Comment: You're missing `FROM qo` before the WHERE

Comment: Where is the partitioning function that `OVER` is supposed to be applied to?